# Clever nagios alert methods

Tags: monitoring, nagios, alerts

We use Nagios, and I get SMSs when something happens. Lots of other sysadmins also get texts. However is there any clever / cool other ways people have gotten nagios alerts?

Comment: This should be a wiki article.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using XMPP / [Jabber](http://www.jabber.org/) to send Instant Messages is pretty popular.  [Here is a short tutorial](http://securfox.wordpress.com/2009/07/09/nagios-jabber-notification/) on how to set this up.

Answer (score 5):

We show nagios alerts on our IRC channel using the NagiosIRC bot

Answer (score 4):

We are using twitter, google chat, mail, and the best thing is the nagios firefox plugin

there are also hardware option like the nagios nabaztag mod

Answer (score 3):

I know of people using push notifications with [Growl](http://growl.info/)/[Prowl](http://prowl.weks.net/) on the iPhone.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to take a look at a project that we're working on called [PagerDuty](http://www.pagerduty.com).  It sends phone call and SMS alerts in response to incoming email.  Quite a few of our customers use us with Nagios.

We've got some other fun features too: automatic escalation (your co-worker gets the call if you're unable to pick up) and on-call rotations (automatically route calls to your phone this week, and to your co-worker next week).

We're always looking to add more features to PagerDuty, so please let us know what you think!

Answer (score 1):

Big red police light, SMS, traditional email, jabber message and a phone call, all depending on SLA on each server. Silent phone calls from a machine at 3am however is never a good thing... Especially when the machine has the audacity to come out of that state as soon as you drag your arse out of bed.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer an actual pager over SMS.  It is decidedly uncool, but they are more reliable and have wider coverage areas where I live.  Also, POTS lines don't go offline as often as internet lines.

Comment: If it works for you, then great. Disclaimer - I've no experience with pagers. But do you really care that it's 'uncool' - as long as it works and gets your job done? +1 for using what works, -1 for self-deprecation :)